# New Route53 record takes very long time to propagate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-route53

So we have a lambda function which is accessible through AWS API Gateway and has a Route53 A type record associated with it which is wildcard domain: "*.testing.pi-dev.net" and is also using SSL certificate.

If I invoke lambda while specifying domain prefix like: "ticket-1.testing.pi-dev.net" it will start new ECS task, create a load balancer for it and Route53 A type record pointing to this load balancer. Record name will be "ticket-1.testing.pi-dev.net". And load balancer will use same SSL certificate as API Gateway/Lambda

Problem is once lambda finishes doing its job it should redirect to new ECS task domain and it is redirecting fine, except that browser is still trying to access lambda. But if I use this link from incognito window or in different browser then it works perfectly.

I am thinking this is some sort of caching issue in browser. I tried clearing DNS cache but that didn't help. This domain started working on my main browser in about 15 minutes.

Maybe there is some specific HTTP header I can return with my response to disable this sort of caching? Here is how I redirect from lambda to my new domain once it finish setting it up:

```
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'headers': {'Location': 'https://' + domainPrefix + '.testing.pi-dev.net'}
}
```

Where 'domainPrefix' is 'ticket-1'

EDIT 1:

I have also tried response codes 302 and 307 as suggested by the answer below. All these codes are just causing "TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error in browser. But in reality once new Route53 record exists it should trigger that record, instead of this it just keeps triggering lambda, presumably because new DNS record for "ticket-1.testing.pi-dev.net" is also part of "*.testing.pi-dev.net" wildcard record.

EDIT 2:

I have found very temporary solution to this problem. Once my new Route53 record is created I have to go to web browser settings and delete "cookies and other site data" and that seems to trigger new Route53 record very nicely. Now my problem is how do I put this logic in lambda code.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a status code 200 instead of a 302/307, so your browser is ignoring the location header.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have tried using "302" before but it still was not working. I will try it again

Comment: I tried both 302 and 307 and browser is complaining about "TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: Are you trying to redirect anywhere else in the pipeline?

Comment: I have added 2 EDITS which you might be interested in reading.